# Does Laravel run services on a schedule by default?

Tags: laravel, api, web-services, scheduled-tasks

UPDATE: I have checked app/Console/Kernel.php, and the schedule function only has the default comment. No scheduled jobs. I also went to the app directory at var/www/laravel where the app lives, and ran `php artisan schedule:list` which returned 'No scheduled tasks have been defined.' There is also nothing in /var/spool/cron/crontabs. This is all the clarity I can provide, thus why I am asking the question if someone else had a similar experience.

I Googled, I searched here, I didn't find my answer. If this is a duplicate to anyone, I apologize.

I have setup a Laravel application with a few different services that consume external APIs, does some basic transformations, then stores to a MySQL database, local to the server. Then, I also have some services that take that new data, transforms the data further, and adds to even more tables.

There's nothing wrong with any of these services, they work as intended, and currently are connected to buttons, via web routes, on a basic UI for testing. The plan is to move these to scheduled tasks, but I've not done anything with automating tasks so far.

However, this is where the question comes in. Does Laravel automatically run services in an app/services directory, by default in production?

I ask because I've never seen my database grow overtime automatically, in local Dev. However, once deployed to a DigitalOcean droplet, I am now seeing MySQL tables, that are connected to those services, growing on their own without my interaction. Again, I've done nothing directly with scheduling anything.

I'd show code, but there's no issues functionally. Just buttons connected to routes, routes to controllers, controllers calling services (app/services) and methods within those services... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's not a job declared in the schedule function or a command that calls a job, then it will not run in production.

Comment: If there are routes/buttons that call services, and thus generate rows in your table, the probable explanation is bots and search engine crawlers accessing these routes.

Comment: @ceejayoz Wow... I had not even thought of bots and crawlers. You are probably right on the money. Time to refactor now that I'm on a live server. It's always the simplest factor hiding in plain sight.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing should be running automatically.

To run tasks use the scheduler: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

You’ll need to [set up a CRON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler) `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` - this runs every minute and will process your tasks. It may be that your hosting has set the sat up for you which is why you’re seeing changes - some Laravel specific hosting can configure this automatically for you.

Comment: I went to the directory, ran php artisan schedule:list, and returned 'No scheduled tasks have been defined.'

Answer (score 1):

Some problems really butter me and after I solved them, that's like a joke. For this problem, check `app\Console\Kernel.php` and the `schedule` function there.

But, I think you didn't change that file, And I think your issue comes from some packages. Just check the packages that you installed in this project.

Comment: I checked the Kernel.php file, and you are correct that I have not changed it. There is only the default comment inside the schedule function. Nothing is set to run.

Comment: @Syntaxed, you need to write your scheduled tasks so they know when and what to run: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#defining-schedules

Comment: @Ric Yep, I refactored to scheduled tasks yesterday. As I mentioned above, the web routes were just for ease of testing services while in dev.